# Odd "List Index out of Bounds (20)" from end of inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

My InnoSetup-created installer gives an odd "List index out of bounds (20)" error message at the very end of it's run.

In the code, if I step through, it happens right after the final "end;" of the "CurStepChanged" procedure.  It has just finished it's switch to ssPostInstall.

The last log messages at this point are:

```
Need to restart Windows? No
Exception message:
Message box (OK):
List index out of bounds (20)
User chose OK.
```

I have no idea where code execution is jumping to next after it leaves CurStepChanged.  Stepping with Inno's "ide" just stops there.  Hit ok on the error dialog and the setup seems to just hang there, but code execution in the IDE never returns.

Comment: You'll need to post the code where you're accessing some collection with a fixed index. FYI, after CurStepChanged can execute e.g CurPageChanged or NextButtonClick events.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the solution in all cases of that error, however, I was using a ProgressPage at the end without hiding it.  Once wrapping the function in a try/finally block and calling the .Hide property, problem went away.

Comment: No, that's not a solution. For you nor for anyone else. A `try..finally` block just ensures the code inside the `finally` part of the block will execute (so I can't imagine how that would fix a list boundary overflow). And calling `Hide` on some object (which you didn't even describe) doesn't either. Most probably you didn't fix the problem. If it's a typo and you meant   that you used `try..except` block, then you just hide the problem. I'm not voting down, just wondering how such a vague Q&A got some upvotes.

Comment: Well, just to verify: 

I removed the try...finally code.  The error is still gone.  
I removed the ProgressPage.Hide call, the error returned.

The actions I took were from the CreateOutputProgressPage help page for Inno, and the CodeDlg.iss example file.  I don't like the idea that I might be covering up something but there's no error being reported now (logs or dialog) so not sure an issue exists now.  It is a try...finally to ensure the execution, no "except" block.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles across this like me. This is indeed the problem. I used a custom progress page myself and forgot to hide it at the end. This caused exactly the same message (List index out of bounds (17)). So the solution is actually hiding the progress page in CurStepChanged.